# EPPlus edited XLSM files show Error in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I use the EPPlus library to batch edit some existing XLSM files. Inside the files I replace a line of VBA code and that's it. Everything works nice, if I edit the same line in the Excel code editor by hand.

When I open some of the files with Excel 2013 (15.0.4989.1000), the following error message is shown.

> We found a problem with some content in 'test.xlsm'. Do you want us to
>   recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook,
>   click Yes.

If I click yes, the repair report shows the following entry. But the message is somewhat too generic to help me further.

> Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml-Part (Arbeitsmappe)

This is my C# code, which edits the XLSM file. Can I update my code or do I have to update the XLSM-file before editing it?

```
static void PatchVba(string filePath, string oldCode, string newCode)
{
    var wbFileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(wbFileInfo, false))
    {
        foreach (var m in package.Workbook.VbaProject.Modules)
        {
            if (m.Code.Contains(oldCode))
            {
                m.Code = m.Code.Replace(oldCode, newCode);
                Console.WriteLine("VBA Patched in \"{0}\"", filePath);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            package.SaveAs(wbFileInfo);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not save patched file \"{0}\".", filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem is. In the edited XLSM-file, a range name is used multiple times with overlapping scope. I was too focused on my C# code to find the root cause.

So removing the named ranges solves the issue. But it would still be interesting to know, why I can edit it without problems using Excel, but not by using EPPlus.

Comment: I've got similar condition. My raw excel has named-value pointing to another excel file which does not exist. Opening the raw excel does not have any problem, but a "enable content" prompt on the top only; but EPPlus' edit will trigger excel's error check/fix.

In my case, I removed that invalid named-value and then it works.

Comment: There is no ample code, because the problem was the Excel Table itself. Just check your named ranges, if there are overlapping ones.